# Is it better to query MongoDB a lot or loop a large array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a large array of objects/documents to be inserted to MongoDB (with Mongoose). But each object has a property that first needs to be filled. Is it faster to query MongoDB for this property for each document. Or is it better to get one big array and loop that every time.

The query and loop would be very simple and the documents queried are small. The collection (and thus the array) has about 3000 items.

At what point do Mongos indexes, native driver, etc. outweigh the overhead of the queries?

Edit:
A simple example would be.

I have an array of documents like this.

```
{
    prop1: 'abc',
    prop2: '123',
    prop3: ''
}
```

And for the value of `prop3` I need to query MongoDB to match `prop1`. Those documents look something like this.

```
{
    prop1: 'abc',
    prop3: 564
}
```

There are about 3000 of these second documents. So do I query them or loop an array

Comment: Some sample documents and pseudo-code would help with visualizing the  problem at hand.

Comment: You question is too broad. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood your question correctly you want to do something as below

1) You have an array which you need to insert in db.

```
var array=[
           {foo: "foo", bar:""},
           {foo: "foo", bar:""},
           {foo: "foo", bar:""}
          ]
```

2) The input array is not complete. You need to assign value to one of the property (in this case **bar**) in each object of the array before inserting in db.

```
var array=[
               {foo: "foo", bar:"bar"},
               {foo: "foo", bar:"bar1"},
               {foo: "foo", bar:"bar2"},
          ]
```

In this situation, i would say looping the array is any day a better option than accessing data base one by one. Remember db operations are more often costly than looping.

You should do

1) 
`var array=[//array goes here ]`

2) Loop through the array and assign value to the property

```
for(//iterate through array){
         //assign the property value
   }
```

3) Insert updated array in database in one go.

Comment: I think he has to get the 'bad' value from the db, so he wants to know if he should query once or n times.  I think your answer is still right, you just didn't capture this aspect.